# open failed: ENOENT with getAbsolutePath()

Tags: java, android, enoent

I have search up for solutions for open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) error but have tired everything and still doesnt work.

I am trying to upload the pictures on my phone to a database that i created on a server.

```
06-01 15:59:32.631 25399-26074/com.example.vikhram.projectv E/Debug: error: /document/primary:Pictures/Pic0601_14Lat_65.6172057.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/primary:Pictures/Pic0601_14Lat_65.6172057.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                                     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                                     at com.example.vikhram.projectv.MainActivity$UploadFileAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:406)
                                                                     at com.example.vikhram.projectv.MainActivity$UploadFileAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:375)
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                  Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                                     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                                     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                                     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                                     at com.example.vikhram.projectv.MainActivity$UploadFileAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:406) 
                                                                     at com.example.vikhram.projectv.MainActivity$UploadFileAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:375) 
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
06-01 15:59:32.631 25399-26074/com.example.vikhram.projectv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                          Process: com.example.vikhram.projectv, PID: 25399
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.InputStream java.net.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.vikhram.projectv.MainActivity$UploadFileAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:459)
                                                                              at com.example.vikhram.projectv.MainActivity$UploadFileAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:375)
                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

That is the error message that I get.

This is the code I run to check the getAbsolutePath();

```
if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // The document selected by the user won't be returned in the intent.
        // Instead, a URI to that document will be contained in the return intent
        // provided to this method as a parameter.
        // Pull that URI using resultData.getData().
        //Uri uri = null;
        if (data != null) {
            //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
           File myFile = new File(selectedImageURI.getPath());
            //File myFile = new File(data.getData().toString());
            //File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));
            //new UploadFileAsync().execute(myFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
            new UploadFileAsync().execute(myFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
            //Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + selectedImageURI.toString());
            //showImage(uri);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File myFile = new File(selectedImageURI.getPath());
```

If you call `getPath()` on a `Uri`, you are doing it wrong, unless that `Uri` has a `file` scheme. Your `Uri` has a `content` scheme. There is no requirement for such a `Uri` to point to a file on the filesystem that you are capable of reading from.

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to open an `InputStream` on the content represented by the `Uri`. Then, use that with whatever `UploadFileAsync` does.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create the parent directories first:

```
myFile.mkdirs();
```